# Python 3.6: How do i get a random index from a 2D array that matches certain criteria into another array?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, multidimensional-array, indexing

Basically I need to create a random playlist of songs from a set library of a genre set by a user. I know how to make the playlist, but when I view the playlist, it shows me the wrong songs. The reason for this is because I make a temporary library with only the songs of that genre and then pick a random song until I have 5 songs but since I'm using the song indexes from the temporary library, they are not the same indexes as the actual library. To solve this I need to instead of putting the songs from the library into the temp library, I need to put the index of the songs into the temp library. My problem is that I don't know how to get the index of the song from the library.

Here is my code:

```
import random
library = [["Song_1", "Artist_1", "Genre_1", 180], ["Song_2", "Artist_2", "Genre_2", 360], ["Song_3", "Artist_3", "Genre_3", 270], ["Song_4", "Artist_2", "Genre_2", 180], ["Song_5", "Artist_3", "Genre_2", 360]]
```

This is my library of songs ^^^

```
playlists = {}
```

I'm using a dictionary for the playlists ^^^

```
def GeneratePlaylistByGenre():
    global library
    global playlists
    temp = []
    playlistName = input("What do you want to call your playlist?")
    playlistGenre = input("What genre do you want in your playlist?")
    for i in range(5):
        song = getSongByGenre(playlistGenre)
        print(song)
        temp.append(song)
    playlists[playlistName] = temp
```

This puts the playlist together^^^

```
def getSongByGenre(playlistGenre):
    tempLibrary = []
    for i in library:
        if i[2] == playlistGenre:
            tempLibrary.append(i)
    song = random.randint(0, (len(tempLibrary)-1))
    return song
```

This gets a random song of the specified genre for the playlist^^^

```
def viewPlaylist():
    playlistName = input("What's the name of your playlist?")
    for i in playlists[playlistName]:
        print(library[i])
```

This is how to view the playlist^^^

```
GeneratePlaylistByGenre()
viewPlaylist()
```

Just Calling the functions^^^

How do i get a random index for the songs in the library that match the inputted genre and add it to the

```
tempLibrary
```

instead of adding the whole song?

Comment: I couldn't find anything anywhere. If it's already answered, please tell me where I can find the solution to my problem!

Comment: if I understood you correctly, you just want the index (within your library-field) of the song (the one you randomly picked)?
I am not a python programmer, but for me it sounds like *library.index(song)* is all you need...

Comment: @Hansa Yes that's what i want! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered by @Hansa in the comments:

```
library.index(song)
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed:

```
library.index(song)
```

is what you want.